# How to save data type "Integer" (nullable int) in Shared Preferences

Tags: android, integer, sharedpreferences, nullable

What is the best way to save null value of data type "Integer" in Shared Preferences.
I can find putInt(which does not allow null values); but no putInteger.

Kindly suggest the proper way to achieve this.

Comment: why need `null` ?

Comment: @Jyotish Biswas Because it may be a value which can be undefined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor#putInt(java.lang.String,%20int)

As long as the `putInt` function only accept the `int` primitive type as its argument. So I think you can't put null value in there.

My suggestion is you should try `putString` instead of it. And when you get the value from `SharePreference`, just parse it into `int` value.

My solution:

```
String value = mSp.getString("YOUR_KEY", "");
if (value.equals("") {
     // Which means it is 'null' number
} else {
     int number = Integer.parseInt(value);
}
```